# Opencart: How to perform some checking before calling $('#form').submit() in admin view?

Tags: opencart

In my admin view (.tpl), I have added a `input checkbox` and `textarea`. When `Save` button is clicked, I'd like to do some checking such as I would like to send the data of `textarea` to store in the database table only if `input checkbox` is checked. Where do I do this checking through PHP? `Save` button has `$('#form').submit()` called through `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the checkbox's input name is `checkbox` and the textarea's name is `textarea`, then in PHP (when saving to DB), You could perform this check:

```php
$textarea = '';

if(!empty($this->request->post['checkbox'])) {
    $textarea = $this->db->escape($this->request->post['textarea']);
}

// save to DB all the values, incl. $textarea - it is either set when chbox was checked or contains no value otherwise
```